# Adding optional parameters to the constructors of multiply-inheriting subclasses of built-in types?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiple-inheritance

My multiple-inheritance-fu is not strong.  I am trying to create a superclass whose `__init__` takes an optional named parameter and subclasses of it which also inherit from built-in types.  Sadly, I appear to have no idea how to make this work:

```
>>> class Super(object):
    name = None
    def __init__(self, *args, name=None, **kwargs):
        self.name = name
        super().__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

>>> class Sub(Super, int):
    pass

>>> Sub(5)
5

>>> Sub(5, name="Foo")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
    Sub(5, name="Foo")
TypeError: 'name' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

(I've also tried it without the `super()` call, but the result was the same.)

Perhaps someone with better knowledge of multiple inheritance can point me in the right direction?

**Update:**

Here is the solution I ended up with, based on [Alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748635/adding-optional-parameters-to-the-constructors-of-multiply-inheriting-subclasses/3748810#3748810).

It's still a little hacky (by changining `__new__`'s signature partway through construction), but it will work as long as the superclass appears in the subclasses' MROs before the built-in type and defining `__new__` this way allows me to make subclasses which work with different built-in types without adding a separate `__new__` to each one.

```
>>> class Super(object):
    name = None
    def __new__(cls, *args, name=None, **kwargs):
        inner = super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        inner.name = name
        return inner

>>> class Sub(Super, int):
    pass

>>> Sub(5)
5

>>> Sub(5, name="Foo")
5

>>> _.name
'Foo'
```

Comment: what is the purpose of the class-level `name = None`? if you mean for it to be there, it should probably be called something distinct from `self.name`

Comment: `__init__` here is stripped down from the one I'm using in the real class, for purposes of demonstration.  The real one doesn't necessarily set `self.name` every time and setting `name = None` in the superclass provides a default value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just cannot pass arbitrary parameters (whether positional or named ones) to an equally arbitrary superclass (i.e., "immediately previous type in the `mro` of whatever the current leaf type is") -- most types and classes just don't accept arbitrary parameters, for excellent reasons too -- quoting from the middle of the `Zen of Python`,

```
Errors should never pass silently.
Unless explicitly silenced.
```

and in most cases, calling (e.g.) `int(name='booga')` **would** of course be an error.

If you want you weirdly-named `class Super` to be able to "pass on" arbitrary parameters, you must also ensure that all classes ever used as bases after it can handle that -- so, for example, `int` can be called with one parameter (or exactly two: a string and a base), so, if it's absolutely crucial to you that `class Sub` *can* multiply inherit from the buck-passing `Super` *and* int, you have to field that, e.g.:

```
class Int(int):
    def __new__(cls, *a, **k):
        return int.__new__(Int, a[0] if a else 0)
```

Note that you must override `__new__`, **not** `__init__` (it does no harm if you *also* override the latter, but it's irrelevant anyway): `int` is immutable so the value has to be set at `__new__` time.

**Now**, things like

```
>>> class X(Super, Int): pass
... 
>>> X(23, za='zo')
23
>>>
```

work.  But note that `X` must subclass from `Int` (our `__new__`-sanitizing version of `int`), **not** from `int` itself, which, quite properly, has an unforgiving `__new__`!-)

Comment: (The names are just for the sake of the example, of course!)  Thanks for the help; I had envisioned `__init__` "consuming" the extra parameter before it was ever seen by `int` (which in retrospect was silly of me).