# Set the value of an argument in a class who inherits from int or float or str

Tags: python, class, inheritance, python-internals

An error is raised when I try to set the value of an argument of a class who inherits from `str`. The error occurs only when I try to access the argument with `myClass(arg = 'test')`. The error is :

```
TypeError: 'arg' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

The issue is shown in this exemple :

```
class A(str):    
    def __init__(self, arg):
        pass

A("test") # Works well
A(arg = "test") # Fails
```

Only the last line raises the error. The previous line works well.
The problem is the same with classes that inherit from `int` or `float`.

**UPDATE (solution) :**

I found a solution with these links :

- [Adding optional parameters to the constructors of multiply-inheriting subclasses of built-in types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748635/adding-optional-parameters-to-the-constructors-of-multiply-inheriting-subclasses)
- [inheritance from str or int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673651/inheritance-from-str-or-int?rq=1)

The solution is :

```
class A(str):

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return str.__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self, arg01):
        print(arg01)

A(arg01= "test")
```

I don't know exactly why that works and I will investigate on it. If someone has got a clear explanation, I'm interested and I thank him in advance.

**UPDATE (my explanation) :**

I'm not sure at all of what I will say but that is what I understood.

Imagine a class `'myClass'` without any heritance.
When I do this `myInstance = myClass()`, here is what happens :

The method `myClass.__new__` is executed. This method will create the object `myInstance`. `__new__` is the real constructor (`__init__` isn't a constructor !). In pseudocode, `__new__` look something like this :

```
def __new__ (cls, *args, **kwargs):

    myInstance = # Do some stuff to create myInstance, an object of the type passed as argument (cls).
    # Add the method __init__ to myInstance.
    # Call __init__ and pass to it the list 'args' and the dictionary 'kwargs' (both come from arguments of __new__). Pass to it also the object itself (self) : 
    obj.__init__(self, args, kwargs) :
        # Do some stuff.
```

The situation is a little different when we are using immutable types (str, int, float, tuple). In the previous pseudocode, I wrote `def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)`. With immutable types, the pseudocode for the method `__new__` is more like this `def __new__(cls, anUniqueValue)`. I don't realy understand why the behavior of `immutableTypes.__new__` is deferent of others but it's the case. You can see it in this exemple :

```
class foo():

    def __init__(self):
        pass

foo.__new__(foo, arg = 1)
# That works because the method __new__ look like this : def __new__(*args, **kargs).

str.__new__(str, arg = 1)
# That fails because we are trying to pass the attribute 'arg' to a method which look like this : def __new__(anUniqueValue).
```

From there, we can understand why the solution presented earlier works. What we do is editing the method `__new__` of an immutable type to works just like a mutable type.

```
def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    return str.__new__(cls)
```

These 2 lines convert  `def __new__ (cls, anUniqueValue)` to `def __new__ (cls, *args, **kwargs)`

I hope my explanation is almost clear and without so much mistakes. If you speak french you can learn more on that link : [http://sametmax.com/la-difference-entre-**new**-et-**init**-en-python/](http://sametmax.com/la-difference-entre-__new__-et-__init__-en-python/)

Comment: Possibly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748635/adding-optional-parameters-to-the-constructors-of-multiply-inheriting-subclasses although I'm not sure what Alex Martelli exactly means by 'equally arbitrary superclass'.

Comment: @Morgan, the explanation is in the linked question, there may also be a *her*  that can provide you with a clear explanation ;)

Comment: @Morgan don't hesitate to answer your own question when you found out what exactly is going on. I did not fully understand the explanations in the linked questions myself.

Comment: @Morgan,  no sweat, it is pretty well explained in the answer so if you have a simpler explanation you should definitely write it as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you wrote is essentially right, there are a few mistakes here and there.

---

```
class A(str):

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return str.__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self, arg01):
        print(arg01)
```

This is not completely correct: if you don't pass any argument to `str.__new__`, your new instance will be the equivalent of an empty string.

```
class A(str):

    def __new__(cls, arg):
        return str.__new__(cls, arg)

    def __init__(self, arg):
        print(arg)
```

In general, `__new__` and `__init__` should have the same signature. It is not a requirement, but in this case you need to pass `arg` to `str.__new__` so you must intercept `arg`.

---

> The method `myClass.__new__` is executed. This method will create the object `myInstance`. `__new__` is the real constructor (`__init__` isn't a constructor !). In pseudocode, `__new__` look something like this :

It is not the responsibility of `__new__` to call `__init__`, as demonstrated by this simple example:

```
class C:

    def __new__(cls):
        print('entering __new__')
        self = super().__new__(cls)
        print('exiting __new__')
        return self

    def __init__(self):
        print('entering __init__')
        super().__init__()
        print('exiting __init__')


C()

# Output:
# entering __new__
# exiting __new__
# entering __init__
# exiting __init__
```

As you can see, in my `__new__` I didn't call `__init__` explicitly, and `object.__new__` is not calling `__init__` either.

`__init__` is automatically called by the Python interpreter itself whenever `__new__` returns an instance of the type.

---

> The situation is a little different when we are using immutable types (str, int, float, tuple).

This is not entirely true. The situation is different **when we are inheriting from a type that is not using the default `__new__` implementation**.

The default `__new__` implementation (i.e. `object.__new__`) is very permissive and ignores every positional argument and keyword argument. If you replace it with a less permissive implementation, then problems like the one you are observing happen.

What is important to understand is that the problem is not brought by the non-default `__new__` itself, but by the fact that **our `__init__` is not compatible with `__new__`**.

---

> ```
>  foo.__new__(foo, arg = 1)
>  # That works because the method __new__ look like this : def __new__(*args, **kargs).
>  str.__new__(str, arg = 1)
>  # That fails because we are trying to pass the attribute 'arg' to a method which look like this : def __new__(anUniqueValue).
> ```

You got it. Just one bit is wrong: the correct signature for `str.__new__` is:

```
def __new__(cls[, object[, encoding[, errors]]])
```

All arguments except `cls` are both positional and keyword argument. In fact you can do:

```
>>> class C(str):
...     def __init__(self, object):
...         pass
... 
>>> C('abc')
'abc'
>>> C(object='abc')
'abc'
```

You see? We used a signature for `__init__` that is compatible with `str.__new__` and now we can avoid overriding `__new__`!